# Behaviour of string.Join

Tags: c#, string

I'm using `string.Join()` to concatenate values with delimiters - here is my simplified example using `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my results:

```
User uItem = new User() { Age = 10, Name = null };

string item1 = string.Join(";", string.Empty, 1); // returns ";1"  
string item2 = string.Join(";", null, 1); // returns ""        
string item3 = string.Join(";", uItem.Name, uItem.Age, 1); // returns ""
string item4 = string.Join(";", 1, null); //returns "1;"
string item5 = string.Join(";", null, uItem.Age, 1); // throws null exception
```

First I was surprised that `item2` doesn't behave like `item1` and determines a `""` instead of `";1"`.

Is there a rule like  *null is allowed but not at the first item?*

**My question:** why does `item3` return `""` and `item5` throws a exception? The input values are equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you are calling different overloads:

```
string item5 = string.Join(";", null, uItem.Age, 1); // throws null exception
```

will call

```
public static string Join(string separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count);
```

(try doing a Go to Definition in Visual Studio and see). So you are passing `null` as the `string[] value`.

For the

```
string item2 = string.Join(";", null, 1); // returns ""
```

there is a remark in the [`String.Join Method (String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) page:

> If the first element of values is null, the Join(String, Object[]) method does not concatenate the elements in values but instead returns String.Empty. A number of workarounds for this issue are available. The easiest is to assign a value of String.Empty to the first element of the array, as the following example shows

I do think that this (the special handling of the fist element) is quite stupid (even because the [`String.Concat Method (Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k9c94ey1.aspx) doesn't have it)

Note that the other overload [`String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992421.aspx) doesn't have this special handling:

```
string item2bis = string.Join(";", (IEnumerable<object>)new object[] { null, 1 }); // returns ";1"
```

If someone is interested, it isn't something random that causes it... There is explicit C# code in the [`String.Join`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,97) implementation of Microsoft:

```
if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == null)
    return String.Empty;
```

Comment: @fubo: because he passes `";", uItem.Name, uItem.Age, 1`. The first parameter is the delimiter, the second one the null-`string[]`, the third the startindex and the last the count. The `params object[]` overload would be taken if he would add another argument.

Comment: @fubo `string.Join(";", null, uItem.Age, 1);`; ";" is `string`, `null` is `string[]`, `uItem.Age` is `int`, `1` is `int`

Comment: Good answer xanatos, and a great demonstration of this 'bug-by-design'.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If separator is null or if **any element of values other than the first element is null, an empty string (String.Empty) is used instead.**

So the different handling of null is by design. Also, as noted by xanatos, using [a different overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx) causes your exception, since it throws an `ArgumentNullException` if:

> value is null

Comment: Doesn't explain the exception, this is one of the questions where it should be possible to accept two answers

Comment: This doesn't explain why `item5` throws an exception. It simply says an empty string will be used instead of `null`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Should be fixed now.

Comment: thanks for your reply i'd accept both answers if i could

Comment: No problem. You are welcome @fubo Xanatos did a great job.